# Get Grid Cell by mouse click

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Grid which is divided into 3 rows and 3 columns,
i wasn't able to find a way of getting the row and column number of mouse click on the net, ohh and if it is possible it will be better for my program that this part will be in code and not XAML,
this is my simple grid:

```
  <Grid Name="GridCtrl" ShowGridLines="True">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question little more...

Answer (score 12):

Faced with the same problem I came up with this solution:

XAML:

```
<Grid Name="myGrid" Background="Transparent" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
```

NOTE: The `Grid` has to be given a background to raise the mouse down event, see: [How to get a Grid to raise MouseDown events when no UIElemets in cells clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511890/how-to-get-a-grid-to-raise-mousedown-events-when-no-uielemets-in-cells-clicked/20512119#20512119)

Code-behind:

```
private void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ClickCount == 2) // for double-click, remove this condition if only want single click
    {
        var point = Mouse.GetPosition(myGrid);

        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        double accumulatedHeight = 0.0;
        double accumulatedWidth = 0.0;

        // calc row mouse was over
        foreach (var rowDefinition in myGrid.RowDefinitions)
        {
            accumulatedHeight += rowDefinition.ActualHeight;
            if (accumulatedHeight >= point.Y)
                break;
            row++;
        }

        // calc col mouse was over
        foreach (var columnDefinition in myGrid.ColumnDefinitions)
        {
            accumulatedWidth += columnDefinition.ActualWidth;
            if (accumulatedWidth >= point.X)
                break;
            col++;
        }

        // row and col now correspond Grid's RowDefinition and ColumnDefinition mouse was 
        // over when double clicked!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's answered here: [Ways to identify which cell was clicked on WPF Grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143849/ways-to-identify-which-cell-was-clicked-on-wpf-grid)

I've never used WPF Grid before, though using that link above as an example I think something like this should do it:

Add this to your Initialize method:

```
this.GridCtrl.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(GridCtrl_MouseDown);
```

And add new method to handle the event:

```
private void GridCtrl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender != null)
    {
        Grid _grid = sender as Grid;
        int _row = (int)_grid.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
        int _column = (int)_grid.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Grid clicked at column {0}, row {1}", _column, _row));
    }
}
```

Comment: _grid.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty); will get the row _grid is in a parent grid, which isn't any

Answer (score -1):

I use something like this:

```
private void DataGrid1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check if the user double-clicked a grid row and not something else
        if (e.OriginalSource == null) return;
        var row = ItemsControl.ContainerFromElement((DataGrid)sender, e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject) as DataGridRow;

        // If so, go ahead and do my thing
        if (row != null)
        {
            var Item = (CLASS_YOU_USE_TO_BIND)DataGrid1.Items[row.GetIndex()];
//Here you can work with Item, it is now the object of class you used in
//DataGrid.DataSource
        }
}
```

Comment: question was about a `Grid` not `DataGrid`

Answer (score -3):

just try this

```
Grid.GetRow(NAME OF GRID)
Grid.GetColumn(NAME OF GRID)
```