# How to get a Grid to raise MouseDown events when no UIElemets in cells clicked?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I observe `Mouse.MouseDown` and `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` are only raised when the mouse is clicked in a cell that contains a `UIElement`, e.g.:

XAML

```
<Window xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Width="300" Height="300">
    <Grid Mouse.MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Fill="Red"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Grid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown raised!");
    }

    private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MouseDown raised!");
    }
}
```

The lines are only written to Debug when the red rectangle is clicked. How can I get the events, or at least one of them, to be raised the grid contains nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the cause of the issue, but as a workaround giving the `Grid` a background, even Transparent, seems to make the events be raised!

```
<Grid Background="Transparent" Mouse.MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
```

Comment: That's not the issue, that is the default behavior.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel there is nothing in documentation about it being the behaviour, why would it be the default?

Comment: I don't know where it is documented but this will answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/5344709/2530848\

Comment: @SriramSakthivel nope that does not answer my question, I already know Transparent is Brush and no-doubt that has something to do with why the work-around works, but does not explain the issue

Comment: I learnt this in pluralsight tutorial by IanGrithfs. I have no clue about where is the documentation sorry:)

Comment: @markmnl - Default background will be `x:Null` which is not hit test visible i.e. not allow mouse events. Refer to this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2507252/632337).