# Grid control clickable and selectable

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to make a **schedular control** a bit like the one inside **Outlook**.

I know devexpress has a control in his library, but I am not willing to pay that much (every year) for this control.

Now the next thing that I need to do is actually make the **grid cells clickable**. Does anybody have an **idea on doing that?**

This is an image of the office behavior I want to create:
[image: Office Behavior]

This is the code I have right now (keep in mind that I will translate this later on to a custom control that reacts dynamicly).

```
<Window x:Class="Ghostware.Scheduler.Example.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ghostware.Scheduler.Example"
        xmlns:scheduler="clr-namespace:Ghostware.Scheduler;assembly=Ghostware.Scheduler"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--<scheduler:Scheduler Margin="5" />-->
        <local:BorderGrid Grid.Row="0">
            <local:BorderGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="17" />
            </local:BorderGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <local:BorderGrid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="22" />
                <RowDefinition MinHeight="22" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2" />
            </local:BorderGrid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="LightBlue">
                <TextBlock Text="Monday 11 July" TextAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Background="LightBlue">
                <TextBlock Text="12 July" TextAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Background="LightBlue">
                <TextBlock Text="13 July" TextAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Background="LightBlue">
                <TextBlock Text="14 July" TextAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Background="LightBlue">
                <TextBlock Text="15 July" TextAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Background="LightBlue"></StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="LightGray"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Background="LightGray"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Background="LightGray"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Background="LightGray"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" Background="LightGray"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" Background="LightGray"></StackPanel>

        </local:BorderGrid>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
            <local:BorderGrid>
                <local:BorderGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </local:BorderGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <local:BorderGrid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="44" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="44" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="44" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="44" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="44" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="44" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="44" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="44" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="44" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="44" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="44" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="44" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="44" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="44" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="44" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="44" />
                </local:BorderGrid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="00 00" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0,2,5,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="01 00" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0,2,5,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="02 00" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0,2,5,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="03 00" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0,2,5,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="04 00" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0,2,5,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="05 00" Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0,2,5,0" />

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="5" Background="Red" Margin="0,0,20,0" />
            </local:BorderGrid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The bordergrid file:

```
public class BorderGrid : Grid
{
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        double leftOffset = 0;
        double topOffset = 0;
        Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Gray, 0.5);
        pen.Freeze();

        foreach (RowDefinition row in RowDefinitions)
        {
            dc.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, topOffset), new Point(this.ActualWidth, topOffset));
            topOffset += row.ActualHeight;
        }

        foreach (ColumnDefinition column in ColumnDefinitions)
        {
            dc.DrawLine(pen, new Point(leftOffset, 0), new Point(leftOffset, ActualHeight));
            leftOffset += column.ActualWidth;
        }

        base.OnRender(dc);
    }
}
```

**Where do I wanna go with this:**

- I have a public github where all the code is on. (Currently working in the other-approach branch). [GITHUB](https://github.com/GhostwareDev/Scheduler.NET/tree/other-approach)
- When I am done I want to make an nuget package of this (there is no opensource solution for a schedular right now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now the next thing that I need to do is actually make the grid cells clickable. Does anybody have an idea on doing that?

You could override the `OnMouseDown` method get the position of the mouse pointer relative to the `Grid` using the solution from here:

[Get Grid Cell by mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363312/get-grid-cell-by-mouse-click)

You could then insert an element in the corresponding cell. Please refer to the following sample code.

```
public class BorderGrid : Grid
{
    public BorderGrid()
    {
        Background = Brushes.Transparent;
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        double leftOffset = 0;
        double topOffset = 0;
        Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Gray, 0.5);
        pen.Freeze();

        foreach (RowDefinition row in RowDefinitions)
        {
            dc.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, topOffset), new Point(this.ActualWidth, topOffset));
            topOffset += row.ActualHeight;
        }

        foreach (ColumnDefinition column in ColumnDefinitions)
        {
            dc.DrawLine(pen, new Point(leftOffset, 0), new Point(leftOffset, ActualHeight));
            leftOffset += column.ActualWidth;
        }

        base.OnRender(dc);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        Point point = Mouse.GetPosition(this);

        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        double accumulatedHeight = 0.0;
        double accumulatedWidth = 0.0;

        foreach (var rowDefinition in RowDefinitions)
        {
            accumulatedHeight += rowDefinition.ActualHeight;
            if (accumulatedHeight >= point.Y)
                break;
            row++;
        }

        foreach (var columnDefinition in ColumnDefinitions)
        {
            accumulatedWidth += columnDefinition.ActualWidth;
            if (accumulatedWidth >= point.X)
                break;
            col++;
        }

        //color cell Red:
        Grid childGrid = new Grid();
        childGrid.Background = Brushes.Red;
        Grid.SetColumn(childGrid, col);
        Grid.SetRow(childGrid, row);
        Children.Add(childGrid);
    }
```

Note that you have to set the Background property of the Grid to a Brush in order for the mouse events to fire.