# Win8 Store App: How to get the row/col index when mouse click on a Grid control?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I want to detect the row/column index of a Grid control when Mouse click a certain slot on that Grid. How to do it?

I am development a Win8 Store application with C#/XAML.

Thanks!

Comment: This has been answered before [Duplicate][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143849/ways-to-identify-which-cell-was-clicked-on-wpf-grid

Answer (score 0):

you should look into [PointerPoint class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.pointerpoint.aspx)

```
PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(gridView);
currentContactPt = pt.Position;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare an array and initialize it's elements with the rows/columns of grid.
Then you can check in a loop which element's mouse click is triggered.